# different pointer addresses in shared library and main application

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

So I have the following code for a shared library **testlib.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int **z;

void f(int *x)
{
    z = &x;
    printf("TESTLIB.C: z = %p, *z = %p, **z = %d\n", z, *z, **z);
}

void f2(void)
{
    printf("TESTLIB.C: z = %p, *z = %p, **z = %d\n", z, *z, **z);
}
```

**testlib.h**:

```
void f(int *);
void f2(void);
```

An application file **test.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "testlib.h"

int main()
{
    int y = 1;
    int *x = &y;

    printf("TEST.C: &x = %p, x = %p\n", (void *)&x, (void *)x);
    f(x);
    f2();

    return 0;
}
```

I compile the shared library testlib.c as

`gcc -shared -fPIC testlib.c -o libtest.so`

and the test.c as

`gcc test.c -o test -L. -ltest`

with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.`

Now the output I get on executing `./test` is

```
TEST.C: &x = 0x7ffcd99e9f40, x = 0x7ffcd99e9f3c
TESTLIB.C: z = 0x7ffcd99e9f18, *z = 0x7ffcd99e9f3c, **z = 1
TESTLIB.C: z = 0x7ffcd99e9f18, *z = 0x7f71cb8af168, **z = 0
TEST.C: &x = 0x7ffcd99e9f40, x = 0x7ffcd99e9f3c, *x = 1
```

Why is the value of `z` on second line not equal to the value of `&x` on the first line? From what I understand the shared libraries are loaded into the same address space as the process loading it right?

Also, why the does `*z` change when `f2()` is called? Is there any way to preserve the value stored in `z` earlier during call to `f()`?

Comment: `z = &x;` - that would be the address of an automatic local variable `x`; it has nothing to do with the *value* you passed from `main()`.

Comment: *Undefined behavior* is invoked because pointer to an object whose lifetime has already ended is dereferenced in `f2()`. Preserving the (meaningless) value of `z` is what you already did.